# Name of a function returning a generator

Tags: python, naming-conventions

How do you name a function that returns a generator (that is, uses `yield foo` instead of `return foo`)?

- It's definitely not `getFoo()` because it does not return a value of Foo.
- It's probably not `foos()` because I'd rather have an easy-to-distinguish prefix.
- It's probably not exactly `listFoo()` because it does not return a `list`.
- It's probably not `iterateFoo()` because this prefix is too long.

What's your preferred solution?

*Update:*

While `foos()` may be a perfectly good solution in some cases, note how method names tend to begin with a verb. The verb conveys the idea that this is a method, not a data field, and thus helps readability. If possible, I'd prefer a solution that makes it easy to tell a method from a data field.

Comment: Who said a prefix is a good thing? How is `foos` not perfectly clear?

Comment: I'm with @delnan on this one. `foos` sounds right. How do you name an iterable (e.g. a list)?

Comment: In my coding practice, underscores in functions names are preferred above CamelCase. I could not find whether this is prescribed in a PEP, but it is in Django docs: "Use underscores, not camelCase, for variable, function and method names (i.e. poll.get_unique_voters(), not poll.getUniqueVoters())." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some terse suggestions:

```
getFoos()
generateFoos()
yieldFoos()
allFoos()
```

Since you don't normally need a generator to just get all your foos, it's pretty common for the specific function of the generator to suggest a more interesting name:

```
getActiveFoos()
getGreenFoos()
getFoosMatchingCriteria(someCriteria)
getFoosOverTheNetworkIfTheDatabaseIsntBeingAJerkface()
```

Comment: ... but one of the core principles of software engineering is that the database is **always** being a jerkface... ;)

Comment: Camelcase might not be regarded as conforming to PEP8 (as far as I see it PEP8 is not explicit about generators).

Answer (score 20):

I think `foo` or `foos` are possibilities. Or, to mimic Python2 dicts' `iteritems`, you could use `iterfoo`.

Answer (score 13):

Although it is good practice to have helpful names that indicate what things do, I do not think it is at all necessary to use [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to indicate the return type of a function.

The return type should probably be documented in comments or the docstring, but I would suggest that something like `foos()`, `getfoos()`, or `get_foos()` would be best for the name.

If you do want it to be obvious that this is a generator, I would suggest `iterfoos()` for its similarity to Python 2's dict methods like `itervalues()`.

Keep in mind that many built-in functions that used to return lists are now generators in Python 3 (`map()`, `dict.values()` etc.), so it should not surprise anyone when your functions that return a sequence are generators even if you didn't call it `generate_foos()` or some other variation.

Comment: I always feel like this is a strange choice to have no hint at all in `dict.values()`. It never bother me as I know what it does, but if someone thinks it returns a list it may lead to (hard to catch) bugs. For example if you do something like this `vals = dict.values()` then you try to get the minimum value `min_value = min(vals)`, everything is just fine, but then you need the maximum `max_value = max(vals)` which gives the following error: `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. The overall behaviour (a "list" that seems to become empty for no reason) is strange and thus hard to get

Answer (score 5):

The most accurate would be:

```
iterateFoo()
iterate_foo()
iter_foo()
iterFoo()
```

You say specifically what the function does while being pretty clear why you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

genFoo()

(...and some extra words ensure this solution has at least 30 characters)